# Library to calculate Distance Metrics on GPU

Tags: machine-learning, gpu

Suggestions of **widely used and fast GPU libraries** that calculate the Euclidean distance of a vector from a matrix of vectors (of the same dimension) ?

Preferably one that works on NVIDIA GPUs.

Need it as a part of comparing solutions that evaluate Radial Basis Function Neural Networks.

Comment: What language you prefer? I estimate writing this function should not take much effort (in c language).

Comment: @William I'll be running these libraries on a small cluster / HPC workstation, so I require libraries with high performance.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using python, use CUDA tool-kit with cudamat library. You will be able to perform matrix operations on GPU using cudamat.

Comment: Can I time these functions to the precision that cudaEvents can ?

Comment: I am not sure about the precision bt in python you can definitely time these functions.